# How to create an inverted index given a list of tuples?

Tags: python, dictionary, inverted-index

For exercising reasons, I have implemented the following function `inverted_idx(data)` that creates an **inverted index** (starting from a list of *tuples*) in which the *keys* of the dictionary are the distinct elements in the list and the *value* associated with each key is a list of indexes of all the tuple having that key.

The function code is:

```
def inverted_idx(data):
    rows = []
    dictionary = {}
    for idx, x in enumerate(data):
        rows.append((idx, x))
    for idx, x in rows:
        for key in x:
            if key in dictionary:
                dictionary[key].append(idx)
            else:
                dictionary[key] = [idx]
    return dictionary
```

By using it on a list of tuples:

```
A = [(10, 4, 53), (0, 3, 10), (12, 6, 2), (8, 4, 0)(12, 3, 9)]
inverted_idx (data = A)
```

Result:

```
{10: [0, 1],
 4: [0, 3],
 53: [0],
 0: [1, 3],
 3: [1, 4],
 12: [2, 4],
 6: [2],
 2: [2],
 8: [3],
 9: [4]}
```

The function works properly, now what I want to do is to modify the function in
order that the inverted index is created just for those elements of the tuples
which occupy the **specific position**. Let's say that I want to get create an
inverted index just for the element in position `1`.

The desired output would be:

```
{4: [0, 3]
3: [1, 4]
6: [2]}
```

How could I change the code in order to create the inverted index just for the element in a given postion?

I have tried to do like this:

```
def inverted_idx(data):
    rows = []
    dictionary = {}
    for idx, x in enumerate(data):
        rows.append((idx, x))
    for idx, x[1] in rows: # trying to access the element in position 1
        for key in x:
            if key in dictionary:
                dictionary[key].append(idx)
            else:
                dictionary[key] = [idx]
    return dictionary
```

But of course, I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-10c9adaea533> in <module>
      1 A = [(10, 4, 53), (0, 3, 10), (12, 6, 2), (8, 4, 0), (12, 3, 9)]
      2
----> 3 inverted_idx(data = A)

<ipython-input-78-d3f320303057> in inverted_idx(data)
      4     for idx, x in enumerate(data):
      5         rows.append((idx, x))
----> 6     for idx, x[1] in rows:
      7         for key in x:
      8             if key in dictionary:

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the solution from Andrej Kesely is a shorter version, I would still like to submit my version that is in your style:

```py
def inverted_idx(data):
    rows = []
    dictionary = {}
    for idx, x in enumerate(data):
        for index, key in enumerate(x):
            if index != 1:
                continue
            if key in dictionary:
                dictionary[key].append(idx)
            else:
                dictionary[key] = [idx]
        rows.append((idx, x))
    return dictionary
```

Returns the following:

```py
{3: [1, 4], 4: [0, 3], 6: [2]}
```

Hope this clears it up. You need to add the index to enumerate the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
A = [(10, 4, 53), (0, 3, 10), (12, 6, 2), (8, 4, 0), (12, 3, 9)]

out = {}
for i, (_, v, _) in enumerate(A):
    out.setdefault(v, []).append(i)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{4: [0, 3], 3: [1, 4], 6: [2]}
```